# how to preserve log files of iisnode?

Tags: node.js, logging, iisnode

I have node.js server running in iisnode. This server serves api request and each request is logged to a file and is stored under iisnode dir. And this log files are not preserved they are deleted after 10 log files are created. So it always maintains set of latest 10.

My question is how to preserve this log, has anyone worked with this setting?
[image: log_files]

Comment: Can you provided your configuration?

Comment: Hi plochie, I am not getting what you are asking for?

Comment: you must have done some configuration for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Open your web.config file and add this `maxLogFiles="100"` to the  section

You can change 100 to your desired value,

Like this;

`<iisnode loggingEnabled="true" devErrorsEnabled="true" maxLogFiles="100"/>`